# CGContext text drawing doesn't scale up on iPhone 4

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios4, core-graphics, iphone-4

I am trying to create an app that scales up nicely on the iPhone 4. Currently most of it scales up perfectly, except for one crucial piece:  the text that I draw inside a CALayer, inside its drawInContext: method. Here is my code:

```
- (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)context {
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context);

    CGContextSetGrayFillColor(context, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    CGContextFillRect(context, self.bounds);

    CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, true);
    CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, true);

    CGContextSetAllowsFontSmoothing(context, true);
    CGContextSetShouldSmoothFonts(context, true);

    CGContextSetAllowsFontSubpixelQuantization(context, true);
    CGContextSetShouldSubpixelQuantizeFonts(context, true);

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0f, self.frame.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0f, -1.0f);

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextSelectFont(context, "CardKit", 30.0f, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFill);
    CGContextShowText(context, "A", sizeof("A"));

    UIGraphicsPopContext();
}
```

This short produce crisp text on both devices, but unfortunately, it produces blurry text on both. Here is how it appears:

[ugly text http://files.droplr.com.s3.amazonaws.com/files/16285043/1gBp61.Screen%20shot%202010-06-26%20at%2021:25:09.png](http://files.droplr.com.s3.amazonaws.com/files/16285043/1gBp61.Screen%20shot%202010-06-26%20at%2021:25:09.png)

That image is taken at 100% zoom on the iPhone 4. What in the world? Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: this is just a guess to look into, I haven't tried to see what it does.   You are currently using 30pt font, you could test the size of the string with 60pt font via (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font and if the width is within your size target rect then draw using 60pt and if not then draw using 30pt.  the iphone4 screen is a direct 2x of the iphone screen, so I'm just guessing that rendering text at twice the point size might work.

Comment: That just makes the letter get cut off. See:  http://zcr.me/01g

Still blurry. Just bigger.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should set the layer's `contentsScale` to be the same as the `scale` of your screen:

```
layer.contentsScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
```

This will scale it correctly on all iOS devices, Retina Display and non-Retina Display. You shouldn't hard-code it to 2.0 (or anything else for that matter) unless you have a good reason to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're dealing with CALayers, you need to set the contentsScale property of your layer to 2.0.

See [this section](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreens/SupportingHiResScreens.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH15-SW1) in the iPhone Application programming guide for iOS 4.

Comment: what happens for non retina display ? Will the text be 50% smaller ?

Comment: Yes, it will appear at the wrong scale (which makes this answer incorrect). To render images that will display correctly on either a Retina or non-Retina display, you should use the `-[UIScreen scale]` property to determine the correct value of `contentsScale`. See my answer to this question…

Answer (score 2):

The link of the previous answer is broken now. New link is [this one](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreens/SupportingHiResScreens.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH15-SW1).